# How to run Streamripper32 from Task Scheduler

Tags: windows-vista, ripping, streamripper32

I'm running Windows Vista and I have a program called [Streamripper32](http://streamripper.sourceforge.net/sr32/) which takes radio streams and separates the songs into separate individual tracks and records them to a folder.

What I want to do is use the Task Scheduler to start and run that program on a schedule.  I've succeeded to make the app open on schedule, but I can't figure out how to make it start ripping.

Task Scheduler has an option to add arguments (in the "actions" tab).  I've tried to add:
`start`, `startrip`, and `run` in that box, and beyond that I don't know what else to try.

Comment: I doubt you'll succeed if you continue using Task Manager. Task *Scheduler* OTOH might help... ;) (And yeah, provide more details.)

Comment: **To closevoters:** The other question is **closed**, and haven't received any answers. This one has a possible answer. What's the meaning of linking to a (closed) post which will not lead anywhere?

Comment: @TFM: If your original question is closed, aren't you supposed to edit and improve it and flag for reopening, instead of posting a duplicate?

Comment: @Karan: It definitely is the standard practice. However, I'm not sure if an answer can be moved, since this question has one, the other doesn't. Closing the other question as a duplicate of this one might also help.

Comment: @TFM now that this one is fleshed out & has an answer - it'll remain open. Close votes age out as well, so it should be fine :)

Answer (score 1):

You want to research the command line parameters associated with the application in question.
Modify whatever command you've got in Task Scheduler to look more like the following:

```
ConsoleWin32 http://scastsrv2.shoutcast.com:8038/ -d K:\Streamrips\ -r 8008 -q -u FreeAmp/2.x
```

I would write out the actual command line you need, but there's no way that I can know what parameters you're going to actually need.